# How do I find out when a stored procedure was last modified or compiled in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I'm preferably looking for a SQL query to accomplish this, but other options might be useful too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT LAST_DDL_TIME, TIMESTAMP
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
AND OBJECT_NAME = 'MY_PROC';
```

**`LAST_DDL_TIME`** is the last time it was compiled.
**`TIMESTAMP`** is the last time it was changed.

Procedures may need to be recompiled even if they have not changed when a dependency changes.

Comment: i cannot find user_objects. Error is occuring while running this query

Comment: @Harie - that's because this question is about Oracle, not SQL Server.

Comment: Does the description of `LAST_DDL_TIME` and `TIMESTAMP` holds ? I just re-compiled a package body (it was invalid): `alter package foo compile body reuse settings;` and both columns where updated. Other difference is that I query `DBA_OBJECTS` (but that shouldn't matter ?).

Comment: @user272735 Which version of Oracle are you on?  I think they enhanced some dependency related stuff in 11 which might have changed this.

Comment: @user272735 In that case, it looks like I'm wrong.  Maybe you should post an answer with script output showing this.

Comment: is it possible to also know from which machine it was compiled from?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, create_date, modify_date 
FROM sys.procedures order by modify_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will do in Oracle

```
 SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'OBJ_NAME' ;
```

Comment: @Thilakan - If you are going to query `ALL_OBJECTS` you should include a predicate on `OWNER` otherwise you may get multiple rows in addition to the `OBJECT_TYPE` predicate from WW's answer a couple years ago.  You should probably also note that `ALL_OBJECTS` contains all the objects the current user has privileges on not all objects in the database which would be in `DBA_OBJECTS`.

Answer (score 0):

I got here when googling for finding PLSQL packages changed after a specific date, a little bit similar to the question above.
Using WW.s answer above I got to this query for finding any "recently" changed objects:

```
SELECT LAST_DDL_TIME, TIMESTAMP, OBJECT_NAME, object_type
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE  -- OBJECT_TYPE IN ( 'PROCEDURE', 'PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY', 'VIEW', 'FUNCTION' ) AND
  TIMESTAMP > '2019-02-20'
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC;
```