# How can I find the last modified date, modified user of an stored procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the user name of the person who modified a particular stored procedure.

[How do I find out when a stored procedure was last modified or compiled in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297392/how-do-i-find-out-when-a-stored-procedure-was-last-modified-or-compiled)

gives me idea about the time. But how do I know the user who modified it?

Comment: See this link for more details : http://izlooite.blogspot.in/2010/12/sql-server-how-to-find-user-who-last.html

Answer (score -11, accepted):

This can be achieve by running any of the following query.

```
SELECT 
    [procedure] = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
        + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])),
    last_execution_time,
    avg_execution_time = CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,2), total_worker_time * 1.0 / execution_count),
    max_worker_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY avg_execution_time DESC;
```

------------OR--------------------------------------

```
SELECT 

COALESCE(DB_NAME(t.[dbid]),'Unknown') AS [DB Name],
ecp.objtype AS [Object Type],
t.[text] AS [Adhoc Batch or Object Call],
SUBSTRING(t.[text], (qs.[statement_start_offset]/2) + 1,
((CASE qs.[statement_end_offset]
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(t.[text]) ELSE qs.[statement_end_offset] END
- qs.[statement_start_offset])/2) + 1) AS [Executed Statement]
,qs.[last_execution_time] AS [Last Exec Time]
,qs.[creation_time] AS [Creation Time]

FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans ecp 
            ON qs.plan_handle = ecp.plan_handle
            CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS t
where
    ecp.objtype = 'Proc'

order by [Last Exec Time]  desc
```

Comment: Were you even answering this question? Neither query does what you asked... In which part of which query do you find what user last modified the procedure?

Comment: Your question asked "I need to find the **user name** of the _person who modified a particular stored procedure_."  These queries do not return any type of username.

Comment: I need a solution that requires less permissions than the above.

Answer (score 26):

Here what it works for me:-

```
DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(255) 
SELECT @FileName = SUBSTRING(path, 0, LEN(path)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path))+1) + '\Log.trc'  
FROM sys.traces   
WHERE is_default = 1;  

SELECT gt.HostName, 
       gt.ApplicationName, 
       gt.NTUserName, 
       gt.NTDomainName, 
       gt.LoginName, 
       gt.SPID, 
       gt.EventClass, 
       te.Name AS EventName,
       gt.EventSubClass,      
       gt.TEXTData, 
       gt.StartTime, 
       gt.EndTime, 
       gt.ObjectName, 
       gt.DatabaseName, 
       gt.FileName, 
       gt.IsSystem
FROM [fn_trace_gettable](@filename, DEFAULT) gt 
JOIN sys.trace_events te ON gt.EventClass = te.trace_event_id 
WHERE EventClass in (164) --AND gt.EventSubClass = 2
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

Source:- https://serverfault.com/questions/258111/finding-out-who-has-modified-a-stored-procedure-on-sql-server

Comment: That query is a thing of beauty.

Answer (score 12):

Can you try this out?

> SELECT name, create_date, modify_date FROM sys.procedures

Comment: I need name of the person who modified. The name what it is listing is the name of Sp

Answer (score 8):

Procedure changes are traced in the system [default trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175513.aspx). Simply open the `.trc` file from your `...\MSSQL\LOG` folder and search for the ALTER PROCEDURE. The only problem is that the default trace gets rewriten in time, so you can only use it for recent changes (days-weeks).

Answer (score 5):

Try *Schema Changes History* Report.

In SQL Server Management Studio -> Right Click on server name or schema name -> Reports -> Standard Reports -> Schema Changes History

This worked for me like a charm.

Taken from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d655e549-c570-4944-b56c-5c28ee942f2b/who-modified-my-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql)

Comment: Very useful information. The caveat is: It will only have default trace (5 files of each 20 MB), which are rotated. So, if the change happened very long ago, we will not able to see it. In that case, we need to have something like extended events, or DDL trigger etc.

Comment: What data source does ***that*** report pull from, though? If it was a table that could be queried in SQL, then this would be a better solution than the above report workaround (which is slow, and is only searchable by exporting it out to Excel... )

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to need this information in the future, it may be worth looking at implementing a [DDL trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on the CREATE_PROCEDURE and ALTER_PROCEDURE [DDL events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542.aspx)

Example B from the [EVENTDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx) page shows a trigger logging all DDL events, with user name captured.

Answer (score 0):

It [*seems*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/6bec119e-90be-42b6-8a76-c7e0128617c3) you cant.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following query and it worked for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
ORDER BY modify_date DESC
```

This query is for stored procedures.