# Find out which account was used to deploy stored procedure or function using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to find out which account was used to deploy a stored procedure or function to a MS SQL Server Database? Anything that works from SQL Server 2008 and up will do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server does not store this information and you will need to create a DDL trigger to capture this information or view your trace file if you have it enabled. Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394888/how-can-i-find-the-last-modified-date-modified-user-of-an-stored-procedure-in-s

Comment: Depending on when it happened, that info may still be in [the default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186). Going forward, you'll need a DDL trigger or maybe, just maybe, don't give so many people permissions to deploy objects.

Comment: ...in other words, you shouldn't have so many people **able** to create stored procedures that you can't just ask them who did it. When you catch a liar, you take their rights away, or maybe before that. Please look up *Principle of least privilege.*

Comment: @AaronBertrand - We don't. Just 2-3 people. But in this case we need to identify who updated a stored procedure.

Comment: Because you can't *ask* 2-3 people and expect an honest answer? If so, it still sounds like *too many people* and/or *the wrong people* have rights they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I can't echo Aaron's comments enough; if you have untrustworthy people, lock them down before they do damage.  However, if that is beyond your ability, or you're building a case to affect such things, here is a script for checking the default trace for historical changes down to login/hostname/application.  It won't tell you exact code changes, but it will tell you who/when.

Just set the date parameter back as far as you need it.  We have this running on a few key production machines to monitor changes... it emails the DBA team hourly when events exist matching our needs.

```
DECLARE @sTracePath VARCHAR(2000), @beginDate DATETIME

SET @beginDate = '2017-05-02 16:00'
SET @sTracePath = (SELECT [Path] from sys.traces where is_default = 1)

SELECT @@SERVERNAME
        ,e.NAME 
        ,case ObjectType 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Index'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Database'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'CHECK Constraint'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Default or DEFAULT Constraint'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'FOREIGN KEY Constraint'
         WHEN 7 THEN 'PRIMARY KEY Constraint'
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Stored Procedure'
         WHEN 9 THEN 'User-Defined Function (UDF)'
         WHEN 13 THEN 'Trigger'
         WHEN 14 THEN 'Inline Function'
         WHEN 15 THEN 'Table Valued UDF'
         WHEN 16 THEN 'UNIQUE Constraint'
         WHEN 17 THEN 'User Table'
         WHEN 18 THEN 'View'
         WHEN 8259 THEN 'Check Constraint'
         WHEN 8260 THEN 'Default (constraint or standalone)'
         WHEN 8262 THEN 'Foreign-key Constraint'
         WHEN 8272 THEN 'Stored Procedure'
         WHEN 8276 THEN 'Trigger on Server'
         WHEN 8277 THEN '(User-defined) Table'
         WHEN 8278 THEN 'View'
         WHEN 16724 THEN 'CLR Trigger'
         WHEN 16964 THEN 'Database'
         WHEN 17232 THEN 'CLR Stored Procedure'
         WHEN 17235 THEN 'Schema'
         WHEN 17491 THEN 'DDL Event'
         WHEN 17747 THEN 'Security Event'
         WHEN 17993 THEN 'Inline Table-valued SQL Function'
         WHEN 18000 THEN 'Partition Function'
         WHEN 18004 THEN 'Table-valued SQL Function'
         WHEN 19280 THEN 'Primary Key'
         WHEN 19538 THEN 'Role'
         WHEN 19539 THEN 'SQL Login'
         WHEN 19543 THEN 'Windows Login'
         WHEN 20038 THEN 'Scalar SQL Function'
         WHEN 20821 THEN 'Unique Constraint'
         WHEN 21076 THEN 'Transact-SQL Trigger'
         WHEN 21318 THEN 'CLR Scalar Function'
         WHEN 21321 THEN 'Inline scalar SQL Function'
         WHEN 21328 THEN 'Partition Scheme'
         WHEN 21333 THEN 'User'
         WHEN 21572 THEN 'Trigger on Database'
         WHEN 21574 THEN 'CLR Table-valued Function'
         WHEN 21577 THEN 'Internal Table (For example, XML Node Table, Queue Table.)'
         WHEN 21825 THEN 'User'
         WHEN 21827 THEN 'User'
         WHEN 21831 THEN 'User'
         WHEN 21843 THEN 'User'
         WHEN 21847 THEN 'User'
         WHEN 22601 THEN 'Index'
         WHEN 22611 THEN 'XMLSchema'
         WHEN 22868 THEN 'Type'
         ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
         end
         ,convert(varchar(25),t.starttime,120)
         ,t.DatabaseName 
         ,objectname
         ,LoginName
         ,t.HostName
         ,t.ApplicationName
        from fn_trace_gettable( @sTracePath , 5 ) as t 
        join sys.trace_events e on e.trace_event_id = t.EventClass 
        where ObjectName is not null 
        and e.name IN ('Object:Altered', 'Object:Deleted','Object:Created')
        and objecttype in (
        1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 8259,   8260,   8262,   8272,   8276,   8277,   8278,   16724,  16964,  17232,  17235,  17491,  17747,  17993,  18000,  18004,  19280,  19538,  19539,  19543,  20038,  20821,  21076,  21318,  21321,  21328,  21333,  21572,  21574,  21577,  21825,  21827,  21831,  21843,  21847,  22601,  22611,  22868
        )

        and starttime > @beginDate
```

You can add things like `and t.DatabaseName!='tempdb'` or `and loginname!='abc123'` to hide noise level changes or things you may not wish to see.

Comment: Some of these things you could capture in a DDL trigger, which could make the response a lot quicker (the e-mail would go out immediately instead of waiting for the schedule)

Comment: @AaronBertrand absolutely yes... however we opted for a more summary type notice rather than one email per change captured.

Comment: @JiggsJedi Thank you so much for sharing this script. However, it only returns events for the current day regardless of the value set in *beginDate*. (See [here](http://imgur.com/a/NvPx6))

Comment: If the default trace is not retaining enough data, you can script it out as a custom trace and set the retention longer on the custom trace.  If you do a custom trace it will need to be re-built on SQL start as it will be dropped on restart.