# How to get Stored Procedure modification history in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

I want to write a query to get the result which should contain all the modifications details of a stored procedure like `LastModifiedTime`, `LastModifiedBy` (we use windows authentication) and if possible to get the information on what was modified in that particular modification.

I have written the below query but it is not sufficient, it gives only the information of last modified, please guide me

```
select 
[database name] = db_name() 
,[schema name] =  SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id])
,name [stored proc name]
,create_date [create date]
,modify_date [last modify date]
from sys.objects
where type = 'P'
and name = 'spName'
```

Comment: is there any way to get the information on who has last modified without using any tool? Is there any free tool? @DaleK

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394888/how-can-i-find-the-last-modified-date-modified-user-of-an-stored-procedure-in-s

Comment: @DaleK no answers helped me in solving my issue

Comment: Maybe you can clarify which of them you tried and in what way they didn't help?

Comment: Tools need to be installed and tracking the information *before* you need it.

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Server does not track changes in the way you require, you need to roll your own implementation or install a 3rd party utility that will do it for you.

Comment: Yes there is a way - you query the information available in your source control system. SQL Server is NOT a source control system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DDL trigger to create a log of changes.

See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/

However, this would be useful only for changes that will happen after you will create the DDL trigger.